# OrientDB Graph editor unable to plot graphs properly

Tags: graph, nodes, orientdb, relationships

The orientDB graph editor cannot handle multiple edges.
For eg I am trying to plot a graph for 20 vertex and 500 edges where vertex are the name of the person and the edges contains the property of timestamp.
But when i try to fire a simple query like ["Select * From Person"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGxkC.png) the canvas is unable to plot the graph properly.

Does orientDB graph editor have a maximum limit on handling the number of edges for a certain vertex? Because when i remove the edges all the vertex are displayed properly.

Are there any possible solutions to configure orientDB so it can handle many edges?

Comment: what do you get? an error?

Comment: The graph editor just stucks. i can't do anything until i clear the canvas.

Comment: Can you check some JS errors?
Do you have a simple dataset to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

which version of orient db you are using? I suspect the prior versions do not support large nodes. Use Orient db enterprise edition 2.2.18, It will solve your problem.